# Is the Macro argument a function?

Tags: function, clojure, macros

I am trying to determine whether a given argument within a macro is a function, something like

```
(defmacro call-special? [a b]
  (if (ifn? a) 
    `(~a ~b)
    `(-> ~b ~a)))
```

So that the following two calls would both generate "Hello World"

```
(call-special #(println % " World") "Hello")
(call-special (println " World") "Hello")
```

However, I can't figure out how to convert "a" into something that ifn? can understand. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to ask yourself *why* you want to define `call-special?` in this way. It doesn't seem particularly useful and doesn't even save you any typing - do you really need a macro to do this?

Having said that, if you are determined to make it work then one option would be to look inside `a` and see if it is a function definition:

```
(defmacro call-special? [a b]
  (if (#{'fn 'fn*} (first a)) 
    `(~a ~b)
    `(-> ~b ~a)))
```

This works because `#()` function literals are expanded into a form as follows:

```
(macroexpand `#(println % " World"))
=> (fn* [p1__2609__2610__auto__] 
     (clojure.core/println p1__2609__2610__auto__ " World"))
```

I still think this solution is rather ugly and prone to failure once you start doing more complicated things (e.g. using nested macros to generate your functions)

Answer (score 2):

First, a couple of points:

1. Macros are simply functions that receive as input [literals, symbols, or collections of literals and symbols], and output [literals, symbols, or collections of literals and symbols]. Arguments are never functions, so you could never directly check the function the symbol maps to.
2. `(call-special #(println % " World") "Hello")` contains reader macro code. Since reader macros are executed before regular macros, you should expand this before doing any more analysis. Do this by applying `(read-string "(call-special #(println % \" World\") \"Hello\")")` which becomes `(call-special (fn* [p1__417#] (println p1__417# "world")) "Hello")`.

While generally speaking, it's not obvious when you would want to use something when you should probably use alternative methods, here's how I would approach it.

You'll need to call `macroexpand-all` on `a`. If the code eventually becomes a `(fn*)` form, then it is guaranteed to be a function. Then you can safely emit (~a ~b). If it macroexpands to eventually be a symbol, you can also emit `(~a ~b)`. If the symbol wasn't a function, then an error would throw at runtime. Lastly, if it macroexpands into a list (a function call or special form call), like `(println ...)`, then you can emit code that uses the thread macro `->`.

You can also cover the cases such as when the form macroexpands into a data structure, but you haven't specified the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`a` in your macro is just a clojure list data structure (it is not a function yet). So basically you need to check whether the data structure `a` will result is a function or not when it is evaluated, which can be done like show below:

```
(defmacro call-special? [a b]
  (if (or (= (first a) 'fn) (= (first a) 'fn*)) 
     `(~a ~b)
     `(-> ~b ~a)))
```

By checking whether the first element of the `a` is symbol `fn*` or `fn`
 which is used to create functions.

This macro will only work for 2 cases: either you pass it a anonymous function or an expression.